# Getting Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'SocketsHttpHandler' exception in .Net 6 Application

Tags: asp.net, azure-functions, dotnet-httpclient, .net-6.0

In one of my Azure Function app(.Net 6 isolated process) and I am making some http requests with a client certificate. I'm registering my services in the Program.cs like this,

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);

services.AddHttpClient().Configure<HttpClientFactoryOptions>(
               "myClient", options =>
                   options.HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions.Add(builder =>
                       builder.PrimaryHandler = handler));

services.AddTransient<IMyCustomClient, MyCustomClient>(provider =>
           new MyCustomClient(provider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>(),
               cutomParameter1, cutomParameter2));

services.AddSingleton<IMyCustomService, MyCustomService>();
```

And injecting MyCustomClient in MyCustomService constructor

```
private readonly IMyCustomClient _myCustomClient;

public PlatformEventManagementService(IMyCustomClient myCustomClient)
{
    _myCustomClient = myCustomClient;
}
```

`var result = await _myCustomClient.GetResponse();`

It works fine for some time and getting the below exception after sending many requests.

`Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'SocketsHttpHandler'.`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are supplying the factory with a single instance of `HttpClientHandler` to use in all clients. Once the default [HandlerLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.http.httpclientfactoryoptions.handlerlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) has elapsed (2 minutes) it will be marked for disposal, with the actual disposal occurring after all existing `HttpClient`s referencing it are disposed.

All clients created after the handler is marked continue to be supplied the soon-to-be disposed handler, leaving them in an invalid state once the disposal is actioned.

To fix this, the factory should be configured to create a new handler for each client. You may wish to use the simpler syntax shown in the MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-the-httpmessagehandler).

```csharp
// Existing syntax
services.AddHttpClient().Configure<HttpClientFactoryOptions>(
                "myClient", options =>
                    options.HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions.Add(builder =>
                    {
                        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);
                        builder.PrimaryHandler = handler;
                    }));

// MS extension method syntax
services
    .AddHttpClient("myClient")
    // Lambda could be static if clientCertificate can be retrieved from static scope
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(_ =>
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);
        return handler;
    });
```